# Остановка рекурсивного setTimeout

Tags: jquery, рекурсия

Есть таймер с рекурсией, мне его нужно остановить на определённом моменте, но он продолжает считать дальше.

Пытался `if(i>stop) clearTimeout(rec);` засунуть внутрь в начало, в конец, вынести за пределы - ничего не помогает..

Что делать?

Код:

```
var i = 0;
var stop = 10;
var rec = setTimeout(function recFun() {
    i++;
    console.info(i);                
    rec = setTimeout(recFun, 300);
}, 300);

if(i>stop) {
    clearTimeout(rec);
}
```

Comment: Суть в том, что есть в условие "остановки" что-то запихать, то оно работает, но вот `clearTimeout(rec);` не работает.

Comment: Ваше условие остановки записано за пределами `recFun()`, а потому оно будет проверено только один раз — сразу же после запуска таймера. Переместите его в конец `recFun()` (аккурат перед закрывающейся фигурной скобкой).

Comment: А в чем смысл кода?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, типо ежесекундный обработчик.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать, подходит не под setTimeout, а под setInterval (периодический запуск таймера). С его помощью вы как раз сможете внутри функции, положенной в setInterval проверять превышен ли порог stop счетчиком i и в этом случае остановить интервальный таймер:

```
var i = 0;
var stop = 10;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  console.info(++i);
  if (i > stop) clearInterval(timer);
}, 300);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает как надо)

Answer (score -1):

Возможно такое решение подойдет:

```
function mySetInterval (delay, delayStop) {
    let idInner = null
    setTimeout( function tick() {
        console.log('tick')
        idInner = setTimeout(tick, delay)
    }, delay)
    setTimeout(() => clearTimeout(idInner), delayStop)

}
mySetInterval(1000, culcDelayStop(5005) )

function culcDelayStop(x) {
    console.log('какие либо вычисления')
    return x
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]